# Jquery UI slider with middle on 0 and background from there

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I want to have a slider with range from -5 to 5 and the middle on 0.
The background color will change from 0

So far I've been only been able to do it with 2 sliders here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ur4SH/

```
<div class="sliders">
   <div id="sliderLeft" class="slider left"></div>
   <div id="sliderRight" class="slider right"></div>
</div>
```

But it is not very elegant and it has some things I don't like:

1. Use of 2 sliders instead of 1
2. I have two handlers and I want only one
3. The drag does not work between sliders 3.

Do you have any ideas how can I improve this or if any solution that only uses one slider exists?

Comment: The only solution found so far is to modify the jQueryUI for the slider. A working exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/srosca/DxK5m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean changing background-color, like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur4SH/1/) ?

I added a new class to CSS:

```
.color {
    background-color: green;   
}
```

and a bit of JS, line 15:

```
$('.ui-slider-range', this).addClass('color');
```

Comment: No. I'm talking to have it just one slider with the range at 0 and going left or right. 
Like a balance slider with the background starting at 0